# How to include nav height on scroll to avoid overlapping?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating an onepager and need my click-to-scroll script to keep a distance from the anchor section and the top of the page in exactly the size of my fixed navigation bar, to have a clean connect when a link is clicked.

I used already a second anchor with a code which looked like this:

```
.anchor-1 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -77px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

But if I use it, my script will not work as it should.

This is my click-to-scroll script with the 'nav-height' included on the sections. Links are active on the perfect position when I'm scolling by myself, but on clicking it's not moving to the perfect position.

```
var sections = $('section')
  , nav = $('nav')
  , nav_height = nav.outerHeight();

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop();

  sections.each(function() {
    var top = $(this).offset().top - nav_height,
        bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();

    if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
      nav.find('a').removeClass('active');
      sections.removeClass('active');

      $(this).addClass('active');
      nav.find('a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

I need to add a nav_height to the scroll position instead of having sections scrolled all the way to the top, to have a perfect distance from the top.